# Generating Very Large Images at Runtime with OpenGL and libgdx

Tags: java, image, opengl, textures, libgdx

I am generating very large hex grids (up to 120k total hexes at 32px wide hexes results in over 12k wide images) and I'm trying to find an efficient way to bind these to OpenGL textures in libgdx. I was thinking of using multiple FBOs and breaking the grid up as necessary into tiles, but I'm not sure how to ensure continuity between the FBOs. I can't start with one massive FBO, because that is backed up by a texture so it would fail from trying to load it to video memory. I can't use a standard bitmap on the heap because I need the drawing functionality of an OpenGL surface.

So what I was thinking was I would need to overdraw on the FBOs and somehow pick up on the next FBO *exactly* where the previous left off. However I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm drawing the hex grid with a series of hexagonal meshes, FYI.

Of course, there's probably some other much simpler and more efficient way to do this that I'm not even thinking of, which is why I pose this question to you fine people!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to draw it in pieces. You need to be able to draw your hex grid from an arbitrary position. This means being able to compute which hexes to draw based on a rectangle overlaid over the map. This isn't a hard problem, and I wouldn't worry too much about drawing extra stuff off-screen. You should master this ability to view the hexmap from any position before moving on.

Once you've mastered that, it's really simple.

Draw the top-left corner and store the pixel data. Then move the area you're drawing over exactly one image width. Draw and store that. Move the area over one image width. Draw and store it. Keep doing that until you've covered the entire width.

Move down one image height and repeat the process. Once you've run out of width and height, you're done. Save your mega-huge image.

You don't need FBOs for this. You could draw it to the screen if you wanted. Though if you want maximum performance, I would suggest using FBOs, double buffering them, and using `glReadPixels` though a [pixel buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object). That should cut down a lot on latency.

Comment: Fantastic answer, and speedy too! Thanks!